# Call methods from array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a class, let's say "A" and an attribute `private $subModules=Array('func1', 'func2')`, where `func1` and `func2` are the names of private methods in class A.

Class A also have a function public, `run()` where I try to run methods from attribute $subModules:

```
class A extends B {
  private $subMethods = Array('func1', 'func2');
  private function func1($a) { // do something }
  private function func2($a) { // do something else}
  public function run() {
     foreach ($this->subMethods as $fnc) {
        call_user_func(array($this, $fnc));
    }
 }
```

Can you tell me what it is wrong with this? I try to do something like this:
`$this->func1('5');`

The error message it is this:

```
   Argument 1 passed to A::func2() must be an instance of B, none given
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
call_user_func(array($this, $fcn));
```

should be:

```
call_user_func(array($this, $fnc));
```

That being said... You dont supply parameters to the private methods... Something like the following will work:

```
<?php

class A {
  private $subMethods = Array('func1', 'func2');
  private function func1($a) { echo '1'.$a; }
  private function func2($a) { echo '2'.$a; }
  public function run($a) {
     foreach ($this->subMethods as $fnc) {
        call_user_func(array($this, $fnc), $a);
    }
 }
}

$a = new A;

$a->run('test');

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, i write example wrong. This is not the problem

Comment: Thank you, i didn't realize i wasn't sending the function parameter.

Comment: @OsomA please mark it as the answer to your question as well ;)